# Terminology: Expected Value, Expectation, Expectation Value

Tags: terminology, expectation

According to [[Wikipedia::Expected Value]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) **expected value** and **expectation** are correct terms for the first moment of a random variable.

What about **expectation value**? I have heard and read this term quite often as well.

Which one should I prefer, and which terms are valid in your view?

Comment: Can you point us to some of the sources where you have seen the term "expectation value"?

Comment: e.g. Wolfram Alpha http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExpectationValue.html, or http://www.rapidtables.com/math/probability/Expectation.htm (where it is used quite interchangeable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `expected value` and `expectation` are the most common in use in the US, I haven't really seen `expectation value` that much.